# EJB3.1 @Schedule in clustered environment

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1, schedule

This is a follow up question to [EJB3.1 Timer cancel issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21651730/ejb3-1-timer-cancel-issue?noredirect=1#comment32735685_21651730)

I used Spring's @Scheduled earlier in my projects. Is EJB3.1 @Schedule similar to that? How does EJB3.1 @Schedule fare in Clustered environment? In a Clustered environment where there are multiple JVMs, how can we make sure only one Scheduler/Timer is run at a time? For example I want inventory level from database emailed to a customer for every hour and I don't want duplicated emails being sent out. I know work around like setting a database flag to avoid further duplication. But, I'm not seeing this as a proper solution. Any ideas on this please?

Comment: if your are using JBoss may be this can be useful. http://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/clustering-session.html

Comment: I am exactly facing the same EJB @Schedule duplicate triggers in clustered env. How did you solve it? Thx